# Does Hebrews 2:3 exclude an apostle from writing Hebrews?

Tags: greek, hebrews, apostle

The Greek of Hebrews 2:2-4 says:

> εἰ γὰρ ὁ δι’ ἀγγέλων λαληθεὶς λόγος ἐγένετο βέβαιος, καὶ πᾶσα παράβασις καὶ παρακοὴ ἔλαβεν ἔνδικον μισθαποδοσίαν
>
> πῶς ἡμεῖς ἐκφευξόμεθα τηλικαύτης ἀμελήσαντες σωτηρίας; ἥτις ἀρχὴν λαβοῦσα λαλεῖσθαι διὰ τοῦ Κυρίου, ὑπὸ τῶν ἀκουσάντων εἰς ἡμᾶς ἐβεβαιώθη,
>
> συνεπιμαρτυροῦντος τοῦ Θεοῦ σημείοις τε καὶ τέρασιν καὶ ποικίλαις δυνάμεσιν καὶ Πνεύματος Ἁγίου μερισμοῖς κατὰ τὴν αὐτοῦ θέλησιν.

The traditional interpretation of this passage (with interpolation):

> For if the word spoken by angels (**angels?**) was stedfast, and every transgression and disobedience received a just recompence of reward;
>
> How shall we escape, if we neglect so great salvation; which at the first began to be spoken by the Lord (**Yeshua**), and was confirmed unto us (**the Christians**) by them (**Apostles**) that heard him (**Yeshua**);
>
> God also bearing them (**Apostles**) witness, both with signs and wonders, and with divers miracles, and gifts of the Holy Ghost, according to his own will?

The KJV with my interpolation:

> For if the word spoken by angels (**messangers/prophets**) was stedfast, and every transgression and disobedience received a just recompence of reward;
>
> How shall we escape, if we neglect so great salvation; which at the first began to be spoken by the Lord (**YHVH**), and was confirmed unto us (**the Jewish people**) by them (**messengers/prophets**) that heard him (**YHVH**);
>
> God also bearing them (**the prophets**) witness, both with signs and wonders, and with divers miracles, and gifts of the Holy Ghost, according to his own will?

Does anything about this text explicitly exclude Peter from being the author of Hebrews?

I'm asking because I'm interested in the idea that Peter wrote Hebrews:

jeffreybowman.com/Authorship_of_Hebrews.html

Comment: Yes, I think there is some added material at the end suggesting that Paul wrote it (without saying so) but that it was not written by an apostle. 2:3 does back that up.

Comment: Thanks @WoundedEgo, but I think it's highly unlikely that Paul wrote Hebrews. There are only nine personal pronouns in Hebrews, and that definitely doesn't sound like Paul. Check this out: http://www.jeffreybowman.com/Authorship_of_Hebrews.html This is a good list, but I think more could be added. For example, the question at the top of the list (for now) on this site is about Peter speaking of a "royal priesthood". I may need to ask a question about this as well, but compare 1 Peter 2:9 to Hebrews 7:20 in Greek http://biblehub.com/interlinear/hebrews/7-20.htm.

Comment: Oh, I agree. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Okay I understand what you meant now. I've wondered if the whole 13th chapter was added, but I can't be sure.  I'm trying to figure out if it's possible that Peter wrote Hebrews. That's what the article is about. There are several similarities (excluding 2 Peter because I don't think Peter had anything to do with that letter) . In fact, I just found 1 Peter 2:3 and Hebrews 6:4. I'll try to work on the question and add more details.

Comment: What's wrong with verse 3?

Comment: @SolaGratia The common interpretation is that "the Lord" is Yeshua, the "us" is the believer writing, and "by them" are the Apostles. This would exclude Peter from being the author of Hebrews.

Comment: That does seem the most apparent interpretation to me, too. Revisiting it, it does seem like it was a collaborative effort of some sort. It actually reads a lot like a Papal Encyclical. Early testimony is heavily toward Pauline authorship. With my limited Greek,  couldn't Verse 22 of the last chapter (13) be saying: "I beseech you therefore, brethen, to be accepting of [this] word of consolation: for in parts did I [i.e. it was I] write to you"? As in, he (Paul?) wrote only some of it? Or does it merely mean he wrote only little? Need someone who knows Greek better.

Comment: Yours is an interesting question. If I find anything more compelling or substantial, I'll let you know.

Comment: I think the interpolations ought to be removed. You're asking for clarity on how to interpret the text, but then inserting your own interpretations...

Comment: @MarkEdward The reason for the interpolations is because the traditional interpretation of this text is well known. Since this is the only verse that is supposed to exclude an Apostle from writing Hebrews, I'm asking if the text allows for a different interpretation.

Comment: @MarkEdward I added the traditional interpretation. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: It is not uncommon (quite the contrary !) for ancient authors to refer to themselves in the third person, nor is it uncommon for speakers (or writers) to include themselves among their audience.

Comment: @Lucian Do you have some evidence to support your claim? Please provide an answer if you do.

Comment: @enegue: Cesar's *De bello gallico* comes to mind, but, as I said, it was quite commonplace.

Comment: @Lucian Are you saying that there's nothing wrong with my given interpretation of this passage, but it's not really necessary concerning whether an Apostle could be the author or not.

Comment: @Lucian Thank you for the example. I have just added a new word to my vocab - ["Illeism"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illeism). As you say, it is not uncommon. I was amused by Salvador Dali when he said of himself, "*Look! Salvador Dali is born.*", and "*Dali is immortal and will not die.*". The last one sits nicely with your statement in a recent answer refuting the idea that people know they will die.

Comment: The Epistle closest to Hebrews is Barnabas', Paul's companion, whose authorship is also disputed. (I cannot offer you any logical explanation for including one while excluding the other, nor am I able to provide a reasonable explanation for the absence of Clement's letter from the New Testament canon, despite its undoubted authorship). Also, would the opposite of *illeism* be *[egoism](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0KaDsxgjNJ8)* ? :-)

Comment: 1Co 9:2 If I be not an apostle unto others, yet doubtless I am to you: for the seal of mine apostleship are ye in the Lord. Though Paul made the claim of apostleship on the grounds of having plowed the soil among the Gentiles, he recognized that there were some who did not think him an apostle in territories plowed by others. I might suggest this is evidence that Paul was the author.

Answer (score 1):

Irrespective of the two possible interpretations of verse 3 that you suggest, nothing in verse 3 (or verses 2-4) alone, as you are asking, excludes Peter from being the author of Hebrews.

The audience, as indicated in verse 3, are those unto whom the great salvation (τηλικαύτης σωτηρίας) that at the first began to be spoken by the Lord (ἥτις ἀρχὴν λαβοῦσα λαλεῖσθαι διὰ τοῦ Κυρίου) was confirmed (ἐβεβαιώθη).  Whatever this group is, ἡμᾶς in verse 3 indicates that the author felt that he (or even she), too, was a member of it.

If this group is understood to represent the Jews, then any Jew could have written the Epistle; if the original 12 Apostles, then any one of the 11 surviving Apostles; if the expanded group of Apostles, including Paul and the Seventy (Luke 10:1-24), then any one of these; etc.

Only if we could somehow reduce those unto whom the great salvation was confirmed down to a group of persons that does not include Peter could we say that Hebrews 2:3 excludes the possibility that Peter wrote the Epistle.  I don't believe this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The salvation spoken of, in Hebrews 2:2-4, is that which the writer warns of being neglected. He does not warn of the neglect of that which preceded it.

For that was the temptation, to revert to that which was precedent.

Thus I believe that *the salvation spoken of* is that which is revealed, specifically, in the passion of Christ, as such. It is this that was, first, *spoken*, by Christ himself, both before and after he suffered; and it is this that was *heard* by certain, of whom the writer is not one.

For he is one of those to whom it is confirmed, not one of those who heard, "this salvation".

Peter heard. Paul had it confirmed. Thus only Paul is in view as one of the possible writers.

If Mark is the young man spoken of, who left his garment and fled, then Mark
did, also, not write Hebrews, I would say.

Nigel.

Comment: An answer to the question being asked should address the text that has been identified. Please edit this answer to that, otherwise it is likely to be deleted.

Comment: Comments duly noted. I have attempted a more clear answer and have adjusted the paragraphs as others have mentioned. Nigel